# What is this small plant with 3 inch long leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

My kid got this from school, in South Korea. The leaves are about 3 inches long and are thick and stiff.

One leaf has fallen off and I re-potted it, but I don't know how to care for it or what to expect. It seems to be doing nothing at all.

[image: Small houseplant. Kind of thick stiff leaves.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to guess and say it looks like a non variegated [*Peperomia clusiifolia*,](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/54416/#b) or it could be [*Peperomia claviformis*](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Peperomia_claviformis_1-OB9.jpg).  I can't decide.

[image: Peperomia-Clusiifolia]

Peperomia-Clusiifolia

[image: Peperomia claviformis]

Peperomia claviformis

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since posting, I was surprised to find a way to get the Korean name, 청페페 (cheongpepe) and which, when searched, gives me results pointing to Peperomia obtusifolia, which seems very close to your answer. Whether it's either of these, I will surely be able to search for some care information now. Thanks!