# Does anyone know what this dark green houseplant is?

Tags: houseplants

I'm not sure what type of plant[image] this is! The leaves are somewhat thick, but I have not been able to figure out what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the stems red? It's not Peperomia teardrop, but might be Peperomia obtusifolia see here https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/what-is-this-small-plant-with-3-inch-long-leaves

Comment: Sorry, I meant Peperomia clusifolia...

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is Peperomia, possibly 'Tear Drop'.  [peperomia plant](https://homegardeners.in/peperomia-plant/)

Comment: This site I've sent says, these plants 'clean the air'.  This is just very silly.  Houseplants do give off moisture H2O and O2 and probably talk to you 'subliminally' but 'detoxification' of the air?  What would the plants be taking out of the air?  CO2?  Not toxic at all...

Comment: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930073077.pdf is where it comes from. In the proper (controlled) environment plants most definitely can scrub the air.

Comment: @stormy - check that link out - many plants absorb indoor pollutants such as formaldehyde, so its not silly at all - they do clean the air, and its nothing to do with CO2

Comment: I just did with my smart hubby as well.  This is just nuts.  Get rid of formaldehyde contributors, get rid of asbestos, get rid of cigarette smoke, burning fumes from the kitchen!  Do not rely on plants to do this work!  Why would anyone rely on plants who are smarter, obviously than us humans, to suck up toxic crap?  They do not clean the air and CO2 was certainly this articles' main 'pollutant'...indoor rooms heavily populated??

Comment: @stormy  you are funny... I don't know why you don't already know this stuff -  unless you're going to live in a home with no carpets, drapes, particle board, pressed wood products like MDF, foam insulation, plywood, resins, some plastics and glues (sounds like a cave to me), all of which produce formaldehyde if not other toxins, you can't get rid of all those sources. See this article here about indoor pollutant cleaning plants https://www.telegraph.co.uk/gardening/how-to-grow/the-best-houseplants-to-clean-the-air-in-your-home-as-recommende/

Comment: @stormy And think about this - if outdoor plants can absorb air pollutants, why do you think indoor ones can't? London Plane trees are well known for their  air pollutant absorbing abilities, but see this article here about air pollution and trees in general https://laqm.defra.gov.uk/laqm-faqs/faq105.html. Never underestimate the ability of plants to contribute to a healthier environment, both in and out of doors.

Comment: @stormy this is your shortest answer ever!  Congrats!

Comment: Kevinsky, very very funny and appreciated.